# Calculate the average speed of a car

Tags: physics, average

A car is traveling from New Haven to Philadelphia. It takes 1 hour and 24 minutes to drive  85 miles from New Haven to New York City. What was the average speed?

First I converted the hour and $24$ min into a decimal:
$$1 \space hour \space and\left(\frac{24}{60}\right) min$$
$$=1.4 \space hrs.$$
Then taking the distance divided by time $$\frac{85}{1.4}=60.71 \space mph$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yep............

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. As a sanity check, you can see that if the car travels at an average speed of 60.71 mph for 1.4 hours, it covers a distance of $60.71 \times 1.4 \approx 85$ miles.